# How to manage URLs in CodeIgniter so they can be updated in a single place

Tags: codeigniter, smarty

I believe Smarty templates has functionality built in that allows you to manage your site URLs from a config file so if something gets moved, you only have to update the URL in one place. Does this sort of functionality exist in CodeIgniter? If not, any pointers or examples on how/where to add it?

For example:

Instead of hard-coding the link it would be: `<a href="<?=$links->settings ?>">Settings</a>`

But where would you want to set $links so that it was available everywhere? Or is it really best to just hard code them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [config](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html) class. It allows you to make custom config files. 
It's not entirely made for URL's but you sure can use them.

Comment: I agree, this looks like the best place to set them up if you were going to do it. Though it sounds like everyone is saying it's not a good idea. I could have swore I saw a PHP project that used SMARTY which managed all the URLs via some sort of config but I cannot find an example. Perhaps that was just custom code the developer on the project wrote.

Answer (score 1):

The base url should be basically right at the start of /app/config/config.php, where app is the name of your codeigniter application folder.  You access it through calls to the `base_url()` function.

Comment: I would suggest doing it this way, all your assets should be called with the `base_url()` function. That way you can easily manage, say a CDN, something easy like this. http://blog.stevenlu.com/2012/06/07/codeigniter-and-cdns/

Comment: I am more concerned with managing the path changing than the domain as all my links are: <a href="/whatever/view/"></a>.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Just be aware that it's a bad long-term strategy to start moving resources around, and compensating with routing.  Your site can turn into a mess of spaghetti before you know it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's called `Routes`, configuration located at `config/routes.php`. [Documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)

If you ask about the rendered html of the links, then your best bet would be using `site_url()` in conjunction with constants, for example `site_url(URL_SETTINGS);`, there is no built in functionality for that, but I can say I don't think that is necessary as it would be used too rarely, but it would influence performance every single load.

Comment: Yea, I meant rendering the links so instead of putting:
<a href="/settings/">settings</a> 

It would be:
<a href=<?=$links->settings ?></a>

And $links->settings would be set in the config or something. That way if I decided to move it to say, /users/settings/ I can just updated it in the config file instead of having to track down every instance of it.

Comment: That's actually bad, you should think of this before you start coding, running that code every time affects performance. But nevertheless, if you need it, use `site_url(CONSTANT_NAME);` as constants are more suitable for this job. Also, the answer below from **Sam Dufel** is suggesting using `base_url()`, it has little difference if you have `mod_rewrite` enabled and your `$config['index_file']` in config is set to "", but, for the sake of portability, as well as to make sure you won't have problems with some libraries, like i18n - use `site_url()` for links and use `base_url()` for assets.

Comment: Btw, if the site uses caching, the performance hit @Vlakarados mentions would be non-existent.